# Why Javascript window.open opens window twice?

Tags: javascript, firefox, redirect

Can you please correct me but why this simple code opens url twice on button click. It happens in Firefox and in some chrome also.

```
function myfunc(){
url = "https://www.google.com/";
cnt=0;
if (cnt==0){
    window.open(url, "_blank");
    cnt=1;
}
    console.log(url);
}
```

Comment: No it isn't opening two tabs.Check your method calling lines.

Comment: When you say, 'opens twice', do you mean that one single button press opens two new tabs in one go, or that you are able to click the button multiple times. It seems that your `cnt` check is designed to prevent the user opening multiple tabs by multiple button presses, however since `cnt` is a local variable and is being set to `0` every time the function runs, your check will never work. If you mean however that one single click opens multiple tabs in one go, then there is nothing in the code you provided which shows that. Maybe you set an `onclick` attribute which you forgot.

Answer (score 0):

var cnt = 0;

Try checking your console for errors. Your cnt was not defined.

Comment: That doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in onclick event which i've attached to video object. If it were div it would work ok but for some reason onclick event run open function twice. Thanx All